# Multiple select2 validation with jqueryvalidation require_from_group method

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I want to validate multiple **select2** elements with the jQuery.validator **require_from_group** method. When I submit the form without selecting any values, the validation works. But after changing the value in any of the select2 elements, the validation no longer occurs.

Here is my codepen demo. Please assist me in solving this issue.
[Demo](http://goo.gl/sPGfCo)

Comment: Why are you using the require_from_group option? Can't you just use required: true? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/advLzY

Comment: @FraserCrosbie  I want at least one is complete. No need all field complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger immediate validation after a user selects a value, use this code:

```
$('select').select2();
$('select').on("change", function(e) {
  $(e.target).valid();
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGpzGg

Comment: Initial part work fine. But problem occur when it has validation error and select a value from one select2 element. Errors only disappear only selected one. Not all elements.

Comment: oh really? for me I do not see that issue. what browser are you using? I am on Chrome with dev tools open and Disable cache on. Also, works on FireFox and Safari.

Comment: I am also using Chrome. please see the example shared by jqueryvalidation site. http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/ . I want something like this. I am really appreciate your help. Thank a lot

Comment: oh I see. You want this to happen immediately. Without clicking validate a second time.

Comment: Yes. Have you any idea to fixe it.??